# How can I prevent a control from reacting to keyboard input without interrupting text input events?

Tags: .net, wpf

I have an application with a toggle button that, when toggled, will listen for text input from a bar code scanner. When the bar code scanner starts sending text input to the application, as soon as it sends a space character, the toggle button (which has keyboard focus) ends up becoming deselected.

I need to find a way to prevent my toggle button from being affected by keyboard input while still allowing the PreviewTextInput or TextInput events to fire.

If I handle the PreviewKeyDown event on the toggle button, I can stop the button from receiving the spacebar input by setting the e.Handled property to true, but that stops the PreviewTextInput and TextInput events from firing.

I've thought about trying to remove focus from the toggle button immediately after it's clicked, but that seems like too much of a hack. I'd also like to avoid sub-classing the toggle button. I've also considered setting the button to disabled and allowing it to be re-enabled with a mouse click, but that's not an elegant solution. I'm thinking there must be some mechanism that associates the space bar key with a button press, and if I could figure out how to disassociate those, I'd have a working solution, but I don't know how that works.

Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Would it be okay to just set the button to not be Focusable?

Comment: Yeah, that's actually a good solution as far as I can tell. It prevents the button from receiving keyboard commands while still being interactive and I can receive my TextInput events like normal. Thanks!

Comment: that doesn't sound like a great idea. How does the user click the button without using the mouse?

Comment: Well, in this case, since the bar code scanner input is identical to keyboard input, we need to ignore all keyboard input while the button is toggled. If we didn't do that, the scanner would rapidly toggle the button on and off while it is scanning characters in because it passes in the space character several times. Basically, we don't want the user to be able to click the button without a mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Mannimarco, a good solution is to set the Focusable property on the toggle button to False.

Answer (score 0):

When the button is clicked set focus to a `TextBox` control to capture the text.
Make the control's background and font the same color to hide the input.

You will have to catch `LostFocus` event and set `e.Handled = false;` while the toggle button is active.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I'd like to avoid shifting focus to another control to capture the text input because I should be able to capture the input within the window itself.